# How to fix this "TypeError: Cannot find function getTime in object"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using this function in a Google Apps Script:

```
function dateDiffYears() {
  var datas = [ [Date(2005, 7, 20), Date(2004, 2, 17)],
              [Date(2008, 9, 1),Date(2007, 5, 25)], 
              [Date(2010, 11, 2),Date(2010, 7, 28)], 
              [Date(2014, 0, 24),Date(2013, 1, 27)] ];

  for (var i= 0; i < datas.length; i++){
    var d1 = datas[i][0];
    var d2 = datas[i][1];
  Logger.log("d2  = " + d2 );
  Logger.log("d2 instanceof Date = " + (d2 instanceof Date) );
  Logger.log("d1  = " + d1 );
  Logger.log("d1 instanceof Date = " + (d1 instanceof Date) );
    var t2 = d2.getTime();
    var t1 = d1.getTime();
    Logger.log("d1 = " + t1);
    Logger.log("d2 = " + t2);
    var result =  parseInt( (t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000) );
    Logger.log("diff = " + result);
       }
}
```

As I can remember, this function worked in the past. But now, when I run it, I got this error message: `TypeError: Cannot find function getTime in object Sun Jan 26 2014 10:23:10 GMT-0200 (BRST). (line 22,` (line 22 is `var t2 = d2.getTime();`). I don't understand this error. What is wrong with the Date(yyyy, mm, dd) formate? And why the error message is talking about today date (ex:`Sun Jan 26 2014 10:23:10 GMT-0200 (BRST)`) since I'm not using `New Date()`?

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: try checking if this is rely Date objects by using ""if (t1 instanceof Date) console.log('this is date');""

Comment: Hi, @VladNikitin, I followed your suggestion, but the logs results are strange, the same value seems to get a false and a true result.

Comment: Are you familiar with chrome dev tools Sources tab, you can watch variables , follow the stack of calls, set breakpoints there. Use it to debug your code and finding out where is the mistake. Or you can give the hole code you are using and i'll try to determine where is the mistake

Comment: Thanks, @VladNikitin, I'll check it. I put all my code (another script where I got the same problem. Any help?

Comment: Try using `new Date(2005, 7, 20)` instead of `Date(2005, 7, 20)` everywhere in the code

Comment: According to [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2), `Date(y, m, d)` returns a *string*. Strings don't have a *getTime* method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand this error because clearly Sun Jan 26 2014 10:23:10 GMT-0200 (BRST) is a date object.

Clearly it *isn't* a `Date` object. Perhaps it's a string, or some Google Apps Script object that gets output a bit like a date but doesn't have a `getTime` function. Perhaps it's a `Range` object containing a date.

If it were a `Date` object, it would have the `getTime` method.

> How to fix it?

Without knowing how you get `d1` and `d2`, it's impossible to say. If it's a `Range` object, for instance, perhaps you can get the date via [`getValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue%28%29).

The first step is to figure out what the object actually is. Perhaps setting a breakpoint on the first line of `dataDiff` and inspecting the arguments.

Comment: Hi, @TJCrowder, I followed your suggestion of inspecting the arguments, but the logs results are strange, since the same value seems to get a false and a true result. Any addicional suggestion?

Comment: @craftApprentice: Sounds like one of the places that the function is getting called, it's getting called with something that isn't a `Date` (even though most of the time it is). You'll need to check your inputs. BTW, I advocate actually using a debugger, not `console.log` statements. It's dramatically more time-effective to see the whole picture.

Comment: @TJCrowder,  I put the entire code, with the input. And I still got the same error. Any further suggestion?

Comment: @craftApprentice: Your update shows code that will definitely not show "true" for `d1 instanceof Date`. `Date(2005, 7, 20)` returns a *string*, not a `Date`. To get a `Date`, you must use `new`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
function dateDiffYears() {
  var datas = [ [Date(2005, 7, 20), Date(2004, 2, 17)],
              [Date(2008, 9, 1),Date(2007, 5, 25)], 
              [Date(2010, 11, 2),Date(2010, 7, 28)], 
              [Date(2014, 0, 24),Date(2013, 1, 27)] ];
```

creates arrays of strings representing the current date and time, it doesn't create Date objects. Further, all arguments are ignored. `Date(andything in here)` is equivalent to:

```
(new Date()).toString();
```

per [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2.1):

> All of the arguments are optional; any arguments supplied are accepted but are completely ignored. A String is created and returned as if by the expression (new Date()).toString()…