# Cant set the value of a cell within a row because it was converted to object or array with no methods

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a function that will iterate over each row in a master spreadsheet and check the value of the 3rd column against every row in a second spreadsheet and compare it with the value in the 6th column, then change the value in the 4th column of the master spreadsheet based on the result. The script is a standalone script because its part of a larger project.

The problem is that when I try to set the value of the 4th column in the spreadsheet, I am getting an error that reads "Cannot find function setValue in object SENT". SENT is the value that is in that cell, and I do not understand how it became an object or how I would need to change to code to get at the value to change it. I checked this post about someone having a problem [not being able to act on a date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363333/how-to-fix-this-typeerror-cannot-find-function-gettime-in-object), but I could not figure out how to take that feedback and apply it to this problem.

```
function eFormCheck() {
  var masterSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mastersheet");
  var masterSheet = masterSS.getSheets()[0];
  var masterRange = masterSheet.getDataRange();
  var masterData = masterRange.getValues();
  var workersCompSent = "SENT";
  var workersCompRec = "RECEIVED";
  var workersCompSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("formsheet");
  var wcSheets = workersCompSS.getSheets()[0];
  var wcRange = wcSheets.getDataRange();
  var wcData = wcRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < masterData.length; i++) {
    var row = masterData[i];
    var email = row[2];
    var rowLog = row[3]; //on my spreadsheet this value is "SENT"
   for (var j = 1; j < wcData.length; j++) {
     var wcRow = wcData[j];
     var wcEmail = wcRow[5];
     if (email == wcEmail) {
         rowLog.setValue(workersCompRec);//having an issue with the value of the third column being an object, but I don't understand how its an object
     }
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setValue()` method only works on the `Range` Class.  You can't chain the `setValue()` method to a variable or a cell value.  You must first define a range.  There are 4 variations of the `getRange()` method.  If you want to set a value in a single cell, then you must get a range that is a single cell.  You may need to use your variable `i` in the `getRange()` method to get the row.  If the column is always the same, then you can "hard code" the column value.

```
sheet.getRange(i, 4).setValue(workersCompRec);
```

Comment: You beat me to it! I think we need a reference question for TypeError messages...

Comment: Yes, that would be good.  A question with a title that is generic enough to cover the general idea, and easy to find.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I did based on your recommendation. I added a variable to the root level of the function "var startRow = 1" and then modified the for loop the if statement. `if (email == wcEmail) {masterSheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(workersCompRec);}`